# Performance issues after upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: query-performance, index, mysql-8.0, my.ini

Recently I upgraded MySQL on my server from newest 5.7.x to newest 8.0.x and I imported my entire database with multi-indexes that I created when I was using MySQL 5.7.x. These indexes optimize SELECT queries that run with WHERE clause on few columns (both INT and VARCHAR columns) on a table that has ~ 8 million records (no JOINs) and they used to work very well, but strangly after the upgrade they do NOT work at all... some queries on this table are MUCH slower :-( We don't want to stay with MySQL 5.7 as it will be discontinued this year. Have you had any similar problem as I have? I tweaked my.ini the same way I did in MySQL 5.7 by increasing buffer sizes, etc. Please help. I will provide more details later if it's necessary like the table structure, example queries and my.ini . Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**
TABLE AND INDEXES DEFINITIONS:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL
> AUTO_INCREMENT,   `imei` char(50) NOT NULL,   `cradle_id` varchar(45)
> NOT NULL,   `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   `event_type`
> int(10) NOT NULL,   `lat` double NOT NULL,   `lon` double NOT NULL,
> `speed` double NOT NULL,   `dtime` datetime NOT NULL,   `force_level`
> double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `duration` double NOT NULL,
> `force_hist` varchar(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'non',   `lr_force_hist`
> varchar(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'non',   `speed_hist` varchar(250) NOT
> NULL DEFAULT 'non',   `milage` double NOT NULL,   `filter` int(11)
> DEFAULT '1',   `filter_reason` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `road_type`
> int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `calibration_variance` double DEFAULT '0',
> `reason` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `reason_other` text,
> `distance_adjustment` float DEFAULT NULL,   `max_speed` smallint(6)
> DEFAULT NULL,   `location_name` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
> `device_id` char(17) DEFAULT NULL,   `utc_offset` int(11) NOT NULL
> DEFAULT '0',   `duplicated` int(11) DEFAULT '0',

```
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
KEY event_index (imei,dtime,event_type,filter), 
KEY event_index2 (device_id,dtime,event_type,filter),
KEY event_index3 (filter)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40026132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SLOW QUERY LOG:

```
Query_time: 2.986858  Lock_time: 0.000001 
    Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 42355 SET timestamp=1680260078;

select *
    from  event
    where  ( ( imei = "0e69eb4e-9999-494c-873d-9416d3569ab0"
                      and  dtime > "2021-12-16 13:23:50" )
              or  ( imei = "ae7f20e8-34d8-48e4-99a1-ff6197bc16ff"
                      and  dtime > "2021-11-17 14:44:05"
                      and  dtime < "2021-12-16 13:23:49" 
                  )
              or  ( imei = "bd415fb6-9a36-493f-ba65-fd54db7e6fce"
                      and  dtime > "2021-01-21 08:46:21"
                      and  dtime < "2021-11-17 14:44:04" 
                  )
              or  ( imei = "357577093449854"
                      and  dtime > "2018-10-07 19:45:26"
                      and  dtime < "2021-01-21 08:46:20" 
                  )
              or  ( imei = "359751080340701"
                      and  dtime > "2017-07-31 11:58:57"
                      and  dtime < "2018-10-07 19:45:25" 
                  )
              or  ( imei = "358979073825062"
                      and  dtime > "2016-10-11 09:02:37"
                      and  dtime < "2017-07-31 11:58:56" ) 
           )
      and  filter != 3
    order by  dtime desc, id desc
    limit  1;
```

EXPLAIN of the above query on MySQL 8.0:

> 1 SIMPLE  event       range   event_index3,event_index    event_index 155     82900   50.00   Using
> index condition; Using MRR; Using filesort

EXPLAIN of the above query on MySQL 5.7:

> 1 SIMPLE  event       range   event_index3,event_index    event_index 155     82900   50.00   Using
> index condition; Using filesort

The query above takes 1.167099 second on MySQL 8.0, but is super fast on MySQL 5.7, only 0.1 second on MySQL 5.7

This happens with default MySQL 8.0 settings in my.ini and also with tweaked my.ini (increased buffer sizes). Both of the databases have KEYRING plugin enabled.

I tried turning off different indexes (setting them INVISIBLE) on MySQL 8.0 but it didn't speed up the query at all.

The server has NVME disk that reads with speed ~ 12 GB/s.

There are about 8 million records in that table. Unfortunatelly I cannot attach entire dump of data here, because it would violate privacy of clients. I can create some dummy data though if you need it to help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information, such as table and index definition, the slow query and the execution plans on 5.7 and 8.0, statistics of tables and columns referenced in predicates.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I EDITED my original question. I hope the information that I attached will help here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks MRR causing the performance regression.
You actually have a better solution to avoid such a performance regression: try to add a composite index on (imei, dtime desc, id desc). It will avoid using MRR and filesort.

-- explanation

1. You only take one row(limit 1)，so you should avoid sorting, which is very expensive(sort all but only take one).
2. To take advantage of the order of an index, the index you use can only take equal conditions in predicate, which is why range conditions shouldn't be considered.

For the new query, my suggestion will be rewriting it to following `union` query with an index on  `event(imei, dtime desc, id desc)`.

```
select PawDT_1680490904511.*
from
   ((select *, event.dtime, event.id
     from event
     where event.imei = '358979073825062' and event.dtime > '2016-10-11 09:02:37'
  and event.dtime < '2017-07-31 11:58:56' and event.filter <> 3 order by event.dtime desc, event.id desc limit 1) 
    union 
    (select *, event.dtime, event.id
     from event
     where event.imei = '0e69eb4e-9999-494c-873d-9416d3569ab0'
  and event.dtime > '2021-12-16 13:23:50' and event.filter <> 3 order by event.dtime desc, event.id desc limit 1)
    union 
    (select *, event.dtime, event.id
     from event
     where event.imei = 'ae7f20e8-34d8-48e4-99a1-ff6197bc16ff'
  and event.dtime > '2021-11-17 14:44:05' and event.dtime < '2021-12-16 13:23:49'
  and event.filter <> 3 order by event.dtime desc, event.id desc limit 1)
    union 
    (select *, event.dtime, event.id
     from event
     where event.imei = 'bd415fb6-9a36-493f-ba65-fd54db7e6fce'
  and event.dtime > '2021-01-21 08:46:21' and event.dtime < '2021-11-17 14:44:04'
  and event.filter <> 3 order by event.dtime desc, event.id desc limit 1)
    union 
    (select *, event.dtime, event.id
     from event
     where event.imei = '357577093449854' and event.dtime > '2018-10-07 19:45:26'
  and event.dtime < '2021-01-21 08:46:20' and event.filter <> 3 order by event.dtime desc, event.id desc limit 1) 
    union 
    (select *, event.dtime, event.id
     from event
     where event.imei = '359751080340701' and event.dtime > '2017-07-31 11:58:57'
  and event.dtime < '2018-10-07 19:45:25' and event.filter <> 3 order by event.dtime desc, event.id desc limit 1)) as PawDT_1680490904511
order by PawDT_1680490904511.dtime desc, PawDT_1680490904511.id desc limit 1
```

The logic is the same for each `union` branch.

Comment: Hi. Why not to include "filter" column as well? As why did you propose such order of columns for new index?

Comment: It accually worked but I need to understand WHY.

Comment: However when I add more imei and dtime conditions to the query then it still uses MRR and becomes much slower.

Comment: I edited my question AGAIN. I posted longer query which has more conditions and this one doesn't work fast in MySQL 8 even with your proposed index (and all previous indexes turned off). What would you suggest for this case?

Comment: Added explanation of previous workable suggestion and the solution to the new query.

Comment: have you got any solution for the performance issue? After upgrading MySQL version 5.7 to 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.04.0, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @KetanPanchal - "Same" is not always the "same".  Start a new Question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Tomas almost has it.  The issue is that `OR` is essentially un-optimizable.  The workaround is to do a `UNION ALL`

Change his answer to

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM (
             ( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 )
             UNION ALL
             ( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 )
             UNION ALL
             ( SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 )
             UNION ALL
             ...
          )
          ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1  -- yes, repeated
```

Without the ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1, it will collect all possible rows before reaching the final `LIMIT` .  This could lead to a bulky temp table and filesort.

Since each test looks for a different `imei`, I feel safe is using `UNION ALL` instead of the slower `UNION` (which implies `DISTINCT`).

I think `INDEX(imei, dtime)` (or at least starting with those 2 columns) will be optimal.

This formulation and index should work well for any MySQL version.

> ... when I add more imei and dtime conditions ...

Consider creating and populating a table that contains those 3 values.  Then `JOIN` to `event` -- no need for `OR` or `UNION`.  And it may be even faster.

Comment: have you got any solution for the performance issue? After upgrading MySQL version 5.7 to 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.04.0, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same thing when doing "in" queries with thousands of values.
It looks like the range optimizer changed how it estimates the memory usage.
The range optimizer tries to estimate how much memory the query will use, and compares it to the variable range_optimizer_max_mem_size. If it comes over this value then it reverts to a full table scan.
The default value for range_optimizer_max_mem_size is around 8 megabytes, and this allows for values ~35k values, which lines up with this [estimation technique](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-optimization-memory-use).

But specifically in mysql 8, if the table has multiple indexes in addition to the one used then it seems to be counting those somehow.
If I have a table with

```
create table parameter_test
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    v1 varchar(64),
    v2 varchar(64),
    v3 varchar(64),
    v4 varchar(64),
    v5 varchar(64),

    index ix_v1 (v1),
    index ix_v2 (v2),
    index ix_v3 (v3),
    index ix_v4 (v4),
    index ix_v5 (v5)
);
```

Then I do

```
select
        *
    from
        parameter_test
    where
        id in (
            1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005,1000006... (thousands of entries)
        );
```

it only goes to 9000 before it switches to a full table scan.

If I drop the varchar indexes then it gets to 34k before it switches to a full table scan.

I can't find any documentation about this change, and I don't know if the memory usage changed, or just the estimation of it changes.

Comment: The "cost-based" Optimizer works with a lot of numbers.  It is not easy to figure out how it comes up with 9K and 34K.  The bottom line is that "IN"has multiple ways of being performed, and the Optimizer sometimes fails to pick the "best" way.